# Bringing HIV Medications from Pakistan to Kyrgyzstan for a friend

Tags: customs-and-immigration, health, pakistani-citizens, kyrgyzstan, hiv

A friend is asking me to buy his HIV and Hepatitis C medicines from Pakistan and travel with them to Kyrgyzstan, where he lives. His doctor here in Pakistan has provided me with his prescription with his name on it, and the medicines. I am worried: what are the risks of bringing these medications with me? How can I decide if I should take them with me or not?

Comment: Is pak Pakistan? Are these medicins legal to have in either country? How well do you know your friend?

Comment: [InternationalPharmacy.com](https://internationalpharmacy.com/restrictions) states: ***Kyrgyzstan** Medicines and vitamins are admitted as authorized by the Bureau for Registration of Medicines and Pharmaceuticals. Prescription drugs should be no more than 3 months’ supply. Non-prescription drugs should be limited to 5 pieces of each item.* It does not mention about taking medicines for other people.

Comment: Please see [Carrying items for other people in my baggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98060/carrying-items-for-other-people-in-my-baggage) and [Carrying medicines internationally for a friend](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23421/carrying-medicines-internationally-for-a-friend/23424). Even if harmless, it seems fairly obvious that if you turn up at customs with prescription drugs bearing someone else's name, you will need rather more than "a friend asked me to" to prevent them being confiscated.

Comment: yes pak is pakistan, and yes they are legal and he is not a very close friend but a friend @Willeke

Comment: @WeatherVane what if i say due to this pandemic he was unable to come to his home land and now he is stuck there so thats why i am carrying his meds.

Comment: @InternationalPharmacy.com i guss its an years supply 4 packs each with 28 tablets and they are pretty expensive

Comment: Bisam it is not me you have to convince.

Comment: If not a very close friend I would tell him to use a postal service. Even for a very close friend I might not carry anything.

Comment: Even if lots of strangers on the Internet said "yeah, it will be okay", I would not do this.  As @Willeke suggests, post it.  When he collects the mail, his name, the package name, and the prescription name will match.  Still not a guarantee but a much better situation than being caught in the airport with drugs with someone else's name on them.